# Automatically converted characters for question title don't appear in page title

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, title

First seen in a Stack Overflow question, but re-created here for testing purposes. The page title and the header displaying the question title above the question disagree on some character replacements. In my testing this included:

1. Many (yes, even more than three) consecutive full-stops get collapsed into one U+2026 Horizontal Ellipsis
2. Two dashes get replaced by U+2013 En Dash
3. Straight quotes (U+0022) get replaced by “curly” quotes (U+201C and U+201D, respectively)

All these replacements *don't* happen in the page title, which makes for funny page titles if you actually include, like, 100 full-stops which get collapsed into a single U+2026 on the page itself.

Comment: I added the `e`s...I wanted to see if it only truncated periods or other characters.

Comment: Well, I wouldn't think that multiple instances of `e` are problematic. Converting 3 or more full stops into an ellipsis makes sense in some way.

Comment: True. But I was curious.

Comment: WTF? Come on, if you must edit the question title, then *at least* don't describe a completely different problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not all browsers can render "special" characters in page titles, so we stick with ASCII there.

(for example, some browsers will even render actual HTML in the title, such as `<b>` and so on)

Comment: Is this still true?  [This title ends in a non-ASCII character](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/319560/why-cant-i-end-a-question-title-with-a-full-stop-sometimes-its-appropriate%ea%93%b8).

Answer (score 4):

Don't post questions with titles containing 100 consecutive full-stops.

Comment: doctor, it hurts when I do this...

Comment: Doesn't address the underlying problem that some replacement logic here operates only on question titles *within* the page and not in the page title. The bunch of full-stops was just what caught my attention. It's not something I do regularly.